# Python Pyspark - Text Analysis / Removing rows if word (value of row) is in a dictionary of stopwords

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

hope someone can help with a simple sentiment analysis in Pyspark. I have a Pyspark dataframe where each row contains a `word`. I also have a dictionary of common `stopwords`.

I want to remove the rows where the `word` (value of the row) is in the `stopwords` dict.

Input:

```
+-------+
|  word |
+-------+
|    the|
|   food|
|     is|
|amazing|
|    and|
|  great|
+-------+

stopwords = {'the', 'is', 'and'}
```

Expected Output:

```
+-------+
|  word |
+-------+
|   food|
|amazing|
|  great|
+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative `isin`:

```py
df = df.filter(~F.col("word").isin(stop_words))
```

where `stop_words`:

```py
stop_words = {"the", "is", "and"}
```

Result:

```
+-------+                                                                       
|word   |
+-------+
|food   |
|amazing|
|great  |
+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create dataframe using the set of `stopwords` then join with input dataframe using `left_anti` join:

```
stopwords_df = spark.createDataFrame([[w] for w in stopwords], ["word"])

result_df = input_df.join(stopwords_df, ["word"], "left_anti")

result_df.show()
#+-------+
#|   word|
#+-------+
#|amazing|
#|   food|
#|  great|
#+-------+
```